# Why this sublimetext build file dont work?

Tags: regex, apache, ide, editor, sublimetext

I am trying to capture the output of the build, for open the file with the syntax error.

This is the build file:

```
{
    "cmd": ["D:\\xampp\\apache\\conf\\buildApache.bat"],
    "file_regex": "of (.*?)(?=:)",
    "line_regex": "line ([0-9]*) ",
    "selector":"source.apacheconf"
}
```

This is the response from the build File

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 19 of D:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:
Invalid command 'Liste', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

What I am trying to do, is when the user, dbl-click on the error, it's will open the file, on line 19.

How Do I write the build file?

Answer (score 0):

In SublimeText 2, The source code file name must appear BEFORE the line number in the build output.

That way, It's impossible to capture the output.

Comment: That appears to be so, but it may be a good idea to expand your regex's to match the text from the beginning of the line. So, your file_regex would look something like: `"file_regex": "AH\d+?: .+line \d+? of (.+?):"`